# LimitRequestBody and ErrorDocument 413

Tags: .htaccess, errordocument

I have in htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 413 /erorr.html
LimitRequestBody 43254412
```

The file erorr.html is on server, exists.

When the limit is excessed I get an error from apache "Request Entity Too Large..." and the redirect is not taking place. What's wrong here ?

Comment: Have you tried reversing the values ? i.e.: 
`LimitRequestBody 43254412`
`ErrorDocument 413 /erorr.html`

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Do you need `LimitRequestBody` ? if not, try remove it.

Comment: Of course I need. If someone try to upload a big file, more than accepted (upload_max_filesize "30M"), the server is still loading. Using LimitRequestBody I can stop this.

Comment: Don't be so sure about that, you can do the same on `.htaccess` with : `php_value upload_max_filesize 40M`and 
`php_value post_max_size 42M`

Comment: Yes, but this values doesn't stop the script from execution, even if the limit is excessed.

Comment: You can check the file size prior to upload using `XMLHttpRequest `, check my demo here: http://pedrolobito.com/demos/html5_file_upload/, this way, you can reject the upload if the file is too big, although, I think you can stop the script execution if the `post_max_size`  exceeds a certain.

Comment: Thank you for your advice Pedro, but this is not a good idea. A file SIZE cannot be checked for real unless it has something to do with the server. As an example, use Scratchpad tool from firefox and change fileSize or edit the entire conditions from your script. Then try to upload a file (as bigger as you want). You just need to send to php a fake size of the file and it will be accepted. Again, the only way to check a file size is using a server side script and not a client side script. Sorry my language. I hope you understand what I wanted to say...